# Is burning token possible

Tags: token

Let's say I am the issuer of the Token A, with 100M supply. 10M are circulating and 90M in reserve, not issued yet. Can I burn them, and reduce the total supply?

Answer (score 0):

You can burn tokens by simply sending (regular payment operation) them to the issuing account.

Answer (score 0):

Visit stellar.expert and search for the keyword "burn".

The address starts with "GALAXY...ZILUTO"